# Changing a model's JSON root when saving to the sever in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a blog application where the API calls the users "Users", but my Ember model is "Author".

```
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true}),
    email: DS.attr()
});
```

I map incoming JSON with an AuthorSerializer:

```
App.AuthorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
        return this.translateRootKey('user', 'author', payload);
    },
    translateRootKey: function(server_word, client_word, payload) {
        var response = {},
            key = payload[server_word] ? client_word : Ember.String.pluralize(client_word),
            value = payload[server_word] ? payload[server_word] : payload[Ember.String.pluralize(server_word)];
        response[key] = value;
        return response;
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to change the root of my POST/PUT when I'm persisting to the server. I want my root to be "user" or "users" (depending on the situation). The server is currently getting this from Ember as its parameters:

```
{"author"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf"}, "user"=>{}}
```

How do I tell Ember to use "user/s" as my key name when talking to the server?

Example:

```
{"user"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf"}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the serializeIntoHash hook.

```
App.AuthorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    hash["user"] = this.serialize(record, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work on the receiving side, as Richard A suggests, below, but the question relates to configuring the sending side.

Comment: Yes, this hook is called just before model.save() is sent to the server

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serializeIntoHash 

"You can use this method to customize the root keys serialized into the JSON. By default the REST Serializer sends camelized root keys. For example, your server may expect underscored root objects."

Comment: @BenWest notice the difference between serialize and serializeIntoHash, the serializeIntoHash give you a chance to change the root key as per the documentation I linked above. You, David or an admin needs to consider making this the accepted answer